# When do Lua strings get instantiated?

Tags: lua

Suppose I have the following loop:

```
for name in poll() do
    if name == "quit" then
        return 0
    end
end
```

Will the `"quit"` string be re-created and cleaned up with every iteration, or will Lua re-use the same instance?

Comment: Check the output of `luac -p -l -l` on this script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just created one time and then it is "internalized", that it is saved in a hash table and then reused.

From [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](https://www.jucs.org/jucs_11_7/the_implementation_of_lua/jucs_11_7_1159_1176_defigueiredo.html)

> Lua internalizes strings using a hash table: it keeps a single copy of
> each string with no duplications.